# share live data between multiple devices in app

Tags: android, web-services, tcp, websocket, http-live-streaming

I want to share live data between multiple devices in a lobby/room setting (where players would join a lobby/room of 4 players etc from the mobile app). The data is not very heavy.

I have thought of storing room data in mysql tables and each phone would hit the Database to get updates of the game (if game is over, other player won etc.) and would also send updates to the Database.

Another solution I have thought of is that the lobby would actually be a web service that would hold all the info and give/receive (JSON POST/GET) updates from the phones.

question: what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you need it to be persistent. A really simple solution is to use web sockets, which allows you to broadcast all messages to a channel, which would be your chatroom

Comment: where is the socket hosted?

Comment: You'd run a node.js server to host. 

https://www.programwitherik.com/getting-started-with-socket-io-node-js-and-express/

Comment: what api/protocol would communicate with the node server from the phone side?

Comment: sorry, web sockets is socket.io which is an API for real time communication